# Javascript Nivo Slider different slide times

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I'm using nivoSlider plugin to slideshow banners on client's website. I need to set different delay times for each slide. I found out this solution:

```
var nivoSliderDelays = [5000,2000,3500];

function setDelay() {
 var currentSlide = $('#slider').data("nivo:vars").currentSlide;
 setTimeout(function () {
  $('#slider').find('a.nivo-nextNav').click()
 }, window.nivoSliderDelays[currentSlide]);
}

$('#slider').nivoSlider({
 pauseTime: 3000,
 startSlide: 0,
 directionNav: true,
 controlNav: true,
 controlNavThumbs: false,
 pauseOnHover: false,
 manualAdvance: true,
 beforeChange: function(){},
 slideshowEnd: function(){},
 lastSlide: function(){},
 afterLoad: function(){ setDelay() },
 afterChange: function(){ setDelay() }
});
```

This seems to work fine as you can see on [client's website](http://www.kikoshop.sk). The problem is that if you navigate by a `controlNav` or `directionNav`, the script goes mad. All set delays seems to change to unexplainable short time and every slide has different timing.

Because client has ability to change timing of each slide by CMS, I had to set nivoSliderDealys as global JavaScript variable, do you think it could be the problem? Do I have any other opportunity to access variables stored in MySQL db from scripts.js?

Answer (score 0):

Might be your problem was causing through controlNav properties, I have just updated some part of code in nivoSlider function, could you add and try.

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({       
        animSpeed: 300,                 // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 3000,               // How long each slide will show
        pauseOnHover: false,             // Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance: true,           // Force manual transitions
        prevText: '<',                // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: '>',                // Next directionNav text
        randomStart: false,             // Start on a random slide
        beforeChange: function(){},     // Triggers before a slide transition
        slideshowEnd: function(){},     // Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){},        // Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){ setDelay() },
        afterChange: function(){ setDelay() }
    });
```

And the problem were causing from the below properties:)

```
    slices: 15,                     // For slice animations
    boxCols: 8,                     // For box animations
    boxRows: 4,
```

Comment: Where can I download the newest version of nivoSlider with updates you made? I downloaded the latest version from github and removed controlNav properties, slices, boxCols and boxRows properties from the list, but nothing changed in result as you can see on website.

Comment: You need to slide it automatically or manually, can you please explain clearly.

Comment: Generaly I expect users will slide it automatically. It still do it the same when I slide it manually, so the delays are ok until I switch the slide. Then the delays look like randomly generated. After a while it gets back set delays automatically and works again as expected.